# Symfony2 - Get Entity Name

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, entity

Im use this code for getting entity name;

```
function setTypeFunction($data)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $type = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($data))->getName();

        return $type;
    }
```

but, this function not give me i want. this returning;

**Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/User**

but, i want just entity name; so "User".

What should i do? I dont wanna use strstrip etc. function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Try ReflectionClass:

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass($data);
$ref->getShortName()
```

---

why don't want to use function?

```
function setTypeFunction($data)
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $type = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($data))->getName();
    $type = end(explode("/",$type));
    return $type;
}
```

Comment: because its not only way. i found it;

$type = new \ReflectionClass($data);
$type = $type->getShortName();

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getshortname.php

thnx for help!

Comment: yeah, at the same time!